# TSQL similar titles from table grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search, grouping

Example:

```
Title                                            Date
Today there was a car accident                   Today
Accident in a particular road                    Today
Weather Report Storm in Country                  Yesterday
A storm approaching from the north of country    Today
```

My idea is to have a query that somehow automatically find most used words in this case '`Accident`' and '`Storm Country`' and from them group them together.

I think the solution should be first I read the titles and then split the titles in words but how to split multiple words so that in end i have something like:

```
Title                                              Date
Today there was a car accident                     Today (latest)
A Storm approaching from the north of country      Today
```

I think this will a lot of people searches, thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?  There are way too many possible combinations of different words and overlapping matches to make this workable as you have currently described it.

Comment: Yeah, doing it for single words would be viable, otherwise the combinations are going to explode. Trivial example: what if you add "Country storm causes accident" to your data above? What would you want the result to look like then?

Comment: My purpose is to make a search out of current news from different feeds and only show one news on Storm Country not having 3-10 feeds and have the same news repeating and populate all page.

Comment: We have a team that did this at work. This is beyond TSQL if it's not a one-off... You want to look into clustering and de-duping before anything goes into the final DB. Ours involved finding what words were best for filtering so we trained an SVM, but if the words change every time you'll need something a bit... smarter.